# How to execute a command on remote server (second level) after logging on a remote server via phpseclib?

Tags: phpseclib

I have to login to a server from a remote server. I am able to login to remote server using phpseclib. After that I am able to login to next server from that but next command executes on firt server and not the second server. For example:

1. Login to server1.example.com via SSH
2. Login to remote-server.example.com using internal script from server1.
3. Execute 'ls'.

ls returns output from server1 rather remote-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure your script on server1 actually logs into remote-server (and does not immediately log out)?  The only explanation I can think of is that the "ls" command is not really run on the remote server.  If you share the script and exact commands, that could help figure it out.  (Output of "script" from the whole exchange might also be helpful.)

Something like the following might also work for you:

```
ssh server1.example.com ssh remote-server.example.com ls
```

Depending on your remote command, you might also do something like:

```
ssh server1.example.com "ssh remote-server.example.com ls"
```

(The latter might be needed if there are, e.g., redirects involved that could otherwise be interpreted by your local shell.)

As you use phpseclib, that might handle the first ssh in the examples above.  So you might perhaps use something like:

```
$ssh->exec("ssh remote-server.example.com ls")
```

Or if you are using public key authentication for the second step, maybe:

```
$ssh->exec("ssh -i ~/.ssh/keyfile remote-server.example.com ls")
```

There's a quick summary of how to run commands remotely with ssh at https://www.ssh.com/ssh/command/

Comment: You guessed it right, i never logged into remote server - key passphrase issues. :( Thanks